# Getting [object Object] when I try to display SQL query results in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm getting started in Node.js and I'm completely confused as to why I can't get the results of my SQL query to render on a page.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM testTable', function selectCb(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  for (var i in rows) {
      console.log(rows[i]);
  }
  res.render('showResults.jade', {
    results: rows
  });
});
```

The results display perfectly in the console, but when I try to render them with Jade I get a number of bullet points (equal to the number of entries in the table), but with each one followed by [object, Object]. This is my Jade file:

```
h1 SQL Results are as follows:
ul
  each item, i in results
    li= item
```

Is there an extra step or something that I need to get the results to display properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output you're seeing is because Jade is simply calling `.toString()` on the result of the expression. And, for `Object`s like `item`, [that's the default result](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2):

```
> {}.toString()
'[object Object]'
```

To get something more useful, you'll have to specify the format:

```
li #{item.prop1} (#{item.prop2})
```

For JSON:

```
li= JSON.stringify(item)
```

---

If you want the format you see with `console.log()`, you can expose the function [it uses](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data), [`util.inspect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors), as a view helper:

```
// Express 3
app.locals.inspect = require('util').inspect;
```

```
li= inspect(item)
```